# Mysql "select * from" doesn't return all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, rows

I'm used to PostgreSQL and don't understand this behaviour on MySQL.

This table (from SugarCRM) has 3057 rows:

```
mysql> SELECT  count(*) FROM tasks ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     3057 |
+----------+
```

But when running `SELECT * FROM tasks` :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tasks ;
...
2344 rows in set (0,02 sec)
```

I'm using a fairly old version of MySQL, but the issue is I'm just trying to dump the database and restore to a new version.

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.51, for slackware-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try `SELECT * FROM tasks LIMIT 4000;`?

Comment: Same result: `2344 rows in set (0,02 sec)`

Comment: What do you get when you run `select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from tasks `?

Comment: This might not be relevant, but the version that you posted is for the MySQL command line client and not for the server. Try `SELECT version()`.

Comment: `select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from tasks` returns 3057 rows. `select SQL_NO_CACHE * from tasks` returns 2344 rows.

Comment: `SELECT version()` shows version `5.1.51` as well.

Comment: Are your tables MYISAM? I ask because of this article: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: Can you show us your schema?

Comment: If it is a MyISAM table try running a `REPAIR TABLE tbl_name`.

Comment: Thank you @Vatev, REPAIR TABLE solved the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally MyISAM table format is very reliable but tables can sometime get corrupted for various reasons like Hardware failures, mysqld process is killed while a write operation is underway, untimely shutdowns or bugs in the MySQL or MyISAM code. If you're using a very old version then bugs are likely.

Before repairing it is recommended that you backup. To repair

```
REPAIR [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] TABLE
tbl_name [, tbl_name] ...
[QUICK] [EXTENDED] [USE_FRM]
```

Comment: Looks like the short answer is already in the comments. But I missed it initially so this might help someone.

Comment: Now it is @ReinstateMonica3167040 ;)