# CDbCommand->queryAll() does not return all rows

Tags: php, yii

```
    $connection = Yii::app()->db;
    $command=$connection->createCommand($sqlStatement);
    $rows=$command->queryAll();
```

I'm comparing SQL run through above code vs. running the same SQL in MySQL Workbench.  And, the two return different number of rows.

MySQL Workbench is returning all the rows.  The above code is always returning a smaller number than the total.

The limit is -1 on the command.  I'm not sure what else to check.  Is there some Yii limit?  A memory constraint limiting rows?  Some kind of cache in Yii?

Is it possible previous SQL statements executed before above code (which is placed in a .php script downstream from a bunch of the SELECT statements) could be affecting this?

I'm new to Yii, but not SQL nor MySQL and rather baffled.

Comment: show the sql statement

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1

Comment: or any table in my database

Comment: Apparently, Yii is not the problem.  Code using mysqli returns less than all the rows, too.  Not sure if driver-related or not.  Wireshark'ing it next, but I don't know much about php+mysql, so would appreciate any deep-dive debugging experience chiming in.

Comment: Could it be something related to mysqli?  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php       Others are having this problem on StackOverflow, too.  But, none are getting answered.

Comment: Using Yii 1 for several years and I never happened anything similar .. .. if you can try using findAllBySql

Answer (score 0):

Listen `queryAll()` returns an array and u need to iterate in order to get all the records.

```
foreach($rows as $row){
  //do something
}
```

Try to query by portions:

```
$limit = 1000 ;
$passes = ceil( Yii::app()->db->createCommand( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM{{test_data}}' )->queryScalar() / $limit ) ;

for ( $pass = 0 ; $pass < $passes ; $pass++ ) {
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from( '{{test_data}}' )
    ->limit( $limit )
    ->offset( $pass * $limit ) ;
$result = $command->queryAll() ; // here is your peace of data
}
```

Comment: I tried iterating, it didn't work because num_rows came back with a smaller number than the total records in the table.  The loop won't exceed num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

This led me to the answer: [Mysql "select * from" doesn't return all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700232/mysql-select-from-doesnt-return-all-rows)

As it turns out, the MySQL database is ISAM.  After doing some cleanup and restore with the database, the queries started returning all the rows.