# Database displays less records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, webmin

I have a file with 4.300.000 records, but when I do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'mytable'`, It just displays 4.270.000. I don't know why is this happening, and I have no idea how to check what's going on. I've tried looking in Webmin, but I don't get it. Do you have any idea of how to see why is this failing?

Thank you and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: I'm betting you've got 30k rows with null values.

Comment: `file with 4.300.000 records` and `mytable` are two completely different things!! Did you import this file into this `mytable` ? If so, have you check the logs for the import?

Comment: `CHECK TABLE mytable`?

Comment: @barry-johnson According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), `count(*)` "returns a count of the number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain NULL values."

Comment: @showdev you are correct. Thank you for the correction. My mistake on MySQL handling of this. From reading the behavior, I bet MySQL actually treats `count(*)` as a count of internal rowids, which could not be null.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, the records of the file are saved in 'mytable'. Where can I check the logs?

Comment: How you know it is 4.3M records? any blank lines in the file? 2) Any rows ignored when duplicated unique keys found when importing?

Comment: Normally at installation folder of mysql take a look at the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

Comment: Possible needs to be repaired, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700232/mysql-select-from-doesnt-return-all-rows

Comment: Possibly innodb row gaps and the thought is driven by a max(id). Who knows as the question is so vague. As such, voting to close as Unclear.